# Error al Editar registro con entityframework C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo que editar un registro que modifica 2 tablas, para lo cual uso el siguiente código.

```
 public static Response EditNewOferta(ViewMtoOferta view, string UserName)
    {
        var oResponse = new Response();
        var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        using (var Transaccion = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {

                //Eliminar las Marcas Ofertas
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var detalleOfertas = db.DetalleOfertas.Where(d => d.MtoOfertaId == view.MtoOfertaId);
                foreach (var Details in detalleOfertas)
                {
                    db.DetalleOfertas.Remove(Details);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                var editOferta = db.MtoOfertas.Find(view.MtoOfertaId);
                editOferta.Partida = view.Partida;
                editOferta.Gpo = view.Gpo;
                editOferta.Gen = view.Gen;
                editOferta.Esp = view.Esp;
                editOferta.Dif = view.Dif;
                editOferta.Var = view.Var;
                editOferta.PrecioOfertado = view.PrecioOfertado;
                editOferta.Descuento = view.Descuento;
                editOferta.MaximoOfertado = view.MaximoOfertado;
                editOferta.MinimoOfertado = view.MinimoOfertado;
                editOferta.PrecioNeto = precioNeto(view.PrecioOfertado, view.Descuento);
                editOferta.MtoProcedimientoId = view.MtoProcedimientoId;
                editOferta.MtoRequerimientoId = (view.MtoRequerimientoId != 0) ? view.MtoRequerimientoId : null;
                editOferta.MtoProveedorId = view.MtoProveedorId;
                editOferta.MontoPartida = view.MontoPartida;
                editOferta.MtoUsuarioId = view.MtoUsuarioId;
                editOferta.RazonSocial = db.MtoProveedores.Where(p => p.MtoProveedorId == view.MtoProveedorId).FirstOrDefault().RazonSocial;

                db.Entry(editOferta).State = EntityState.Modified;
                var response = DBHelper.SaveChanges(db);

                if (response.succeeded)
                {
                    var DetailsTemp = view.DetalleOfertas.ToList();

                    foreach (var Details in DetailsTemp)
                    {
                        var Marcasdet = new DetalleOferta
                        {
                            MtoOfertaId = editOferta.MtoOfertaId,
                            OficioExime = Details.OficioExime == null ? "NA" : Details.OficioExime.ToUpper().Trim(),
                            TramiteInclusion = Details.TramiteInclusion == null ? "NA" : Details.TramiteInclusion.ToUpper().Trim(),
                            Marca = Details.Marca.ToUpper().Trim(),
                            RegistroSanitario = Details.RegistroSanitario.ToUpper().Trim(),
                            TitularRegistro = Details.TitularRegistro,
                            RfcTitular = ComboHelper.GetByRfc(Details.TitularRegistro.ToUpper().Trim()).FirstOrDefault().RfcProveedor,
                            Origen = Details.Origen.ToUpper().Trim(),
                            Fabricante = Details.Fabricante,
                            RfcFabricante = ComboHelper.GetByRfc(Details.Fabricante.ToUpper().Trim()).FirstOrDefault().RfcProveedor,

                        };

                        db.DetalleOfertas.Add(Marcasdet);
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    Transaccion.Commit();
                    oResponse.succeeded = true;

                }

                return oResponse;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Transaccion.Rollback();
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);

                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                oResponse.Message = raise.Message;
                return oResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

                if (Ex.InnerException != null &&
                    Ex.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
                    Ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToUpper().Contains("_INDEX"))
                {
                    oResponse.Message = "There is a record with the same value";
                }
                else if (Ex.InnerException != null &&
                  Ex.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
                  Ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToUpper().Contains("REFERENCE"))
                {
                    oResponse.Message = "The record can´t be delete  because it has  related records";
                }
                else if (Ex.InnerException != null &&
                  Ex.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
                  Ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToUpper().Contains("FOREING"))
                {
                    oResponse.Message = "Error al intentar almacenar el registro, pongase en contacto con el Administrador";
                }
                else
                {
                    oResponse.Message = Ex.Message;
                }
                return oResponse;
            }
        }
    }
```

sin embargo en algunas ocasiones cuando están trabajando entre 5 y 7 usuarios dentro del sistema me manda el siguiente error.

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).        Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
```

ya revise el codigo, pero no encuentro el error, es por ello que acudo a ustedes; les comento que al parecer esto empezo a suceder cuando sin querer actualize framework.

saludos.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Comment: si entiendo la situación el problema es que pasa cuando se llama a la opción de editar y si por ejemplo se esta editando el registro con id 3, y otro usuario edita el registro con id 1500, ya ninguno de los 2 procedimientos se lleva a cabo y deja de funcionar.